# Grouping parallel runs in one entry on Cypress.io using Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, cypress, nrwl-nx

I have an `Nx` project with `Gitlab CI` configured. My project has 2 kinds of E2E testing included - main project's and Storybook's ones. The tests themselves work fine, but I use `cypress.io` dashboard for E2E results gathering.

I configured the project to record them and it works, but I want them to be saved as one run, but with 2 groups x 2 browsers (Main/Storybook x Chrome/Firefox). Recording also works fine, `cypress.io` dashboard recognizes 2 browsers and groups correctly, but I only get results for one browser (there is one result for Chrome for Main and one for Firefox for Storybook - the second browsers are visible in filters, but results for them are empty - please, see the screenshots).

[image: One test run with correct groups and browsers]

[image: No results for Firefox for Main]

I tried some flags and configurations from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization.html

Unfortunately, no matter what I try, there is always some kind of error like:

> You passed the --parallel flag, but we do not parallelize tests across
> different environments. This machine is sending different environment
> parameters than the first machine that started this parallel run. The
> existing run is: https://dashboard.cypress.io/projects/qwerty/runs/44
> In order to run in parallel mode each machine must send identical
> environment parameters such as:
>
> - specs
> - osName
> - osVersion
> - browserName
> - browserVersion (major) This machine sent the following parameters: {   "osName": "linux",   "osVersion": "Ubuntu - 20.04",   "browserName":
>   "Firefox",   "browserVersion": "80.0.1",   "specs": [
>   "src/integration/app/app.spec.ts"   ] } https://on.cypress.io/parallel-group-params-mismatch

Only one browser per group passes and the 2nd one gets the following error.

[image: Pipeline result]

These are my scripts in `package.json`:

```
# 1st --parallel flag for nx and 2nd after -- for Cypress directly
# $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY - key provided by cypress.io
# $CI_ID - <branch-name>-<commit-hash> - e.g. my-new-branch-qweqtwerwtreyzsxfc4123dxfv

"e2e:ci": "nx e2e main-e2e --prod --headless --parallel --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --ci-build-id $CI_ID --group MainWeb -- --parallel",
"e2e:ci:chrome": "yarn e2e:ci --browser=chrome",
"e2e:ci:firefox": "yarn e2e:ci --browser=firefox",

"e2e:storybook:ci": "nx e2e storybook-e2e --prod --headless --parallel --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --ci-build-id $CI_ID --group Storybook -- --parallel",
"e2e:storybook:ci:chrome": "yarn e2e:storybook:ci --browser=chrome",
"e2e:storybook:ci:firefox": "yarn e2e:storybook:ci --browser=firefox"
```

And here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` (e2e stage part only):

```
E2E Main-Web - Chrome:
  stage: e2e
  script:
    - yarn e2e:ci:chrome

E2E Main-Web - Firefox:
  stage: e2e
  script:
    - yarn e2e:ci:firefox

E2E Storybook - Chrome:
  stage: e2e
  script:
    - yarn e2e:storybook:ci:chrome

E2E Storybook - Firefox:
  stage: e2e
  script:
    - yarn e2e:storybook:ci:firefox
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here. I tried so many configurations, flags, solutions (even parallelization on Gitlab), but always there is something wrong...

Of course I set `cypress.io > Project Settings > Parallelization > Run Completion Delay` for `60s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer lies in the Cypress error you shared:

> You passed the --parallel flag, but we do not parallelize tests across
> different environments.

You are triggering two parallel runs, with each parallel run setting up two browsers. As the error says, this is not expected - each parallel run should have only *one* browser.

The solution in this case is easy: just configure four groups, one for each test and browser type.

This is how this could look:

```
"e2e:ci": "nx e2e main-e2e --prod --headless --parallel --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --ci-build-id $CI_ID -- --parallel",
"e2e:ci:chrome": "yarn e2e:ci --browser=chrome --group 'MainWeb Chrome' ",
"e2e:ci:firefox": "yarn e2e:ci --browser=firefox --group 'MainWeb Firefox' ",

"e2e:storybook:ci": "nx e2e storybook-e2e --prod --headless --parallel --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --ci-build-id $CI_ID -- --parallel",
"e2e:storybook:ci:chrome": "yarn e2e:storybook:ci --browser=chrome --group 'Storybook Chrome'",
"e2e:storybook:ci:firefox": "yarn e2e:storybook:ci --browser=firefox --group 'Storybook Firefox'"
```

Comment: It worked, the pipeline is green now, but... Now I have 4 groups, so it detects I ran my tests against 2 browsers, but I cannot filter them. Ofc both are visible in filters, but because I created 4 groups, there is only one result (for one browser) within one group. The solution is kinda okay, I can live with it, but it's not "perfect". I guess, the only solution to have browser filters is to record Main and Storybook separately, without groups (just parallel flag with different build CI IDs).

Comment: Is it on purpose that the `e2e:ci` command has `--parallel` two times?